# Box shadow of child element appearing on top of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now I'm using box shadow for both the parent (`.map`) and child (`.toggle-button`):

```
.map {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    width: 280px;
    height: 280px;
    z-index: 9999;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.map .toggle-button {
    background: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: -20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 68px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

But the shadow of the child appears on top of the parent:

[image]

And I can't put the parent on top of the child because the shadow of the parent will display on top of the child.

How to retain the shadow for both while making both elements look as one?

Live example: https://desolate-island-90618.herokuapp.com/#!/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in the class `.map .toggle-button` the following line of code, from:

```css
box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
```

to:

```css
box-shadow: -6px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the angle of the shadow will help you out.. Update your code like below..

```
.map .toggle-button{
   box-shadow:-6px 1px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```